# T-SQL parameter sniffing recompile plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the SQL command

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) * FROM mytableView WHERE ([Name]) LIKE (''%'' + 
  (@Value0) + ''%'') ORDER BY [Id] DESC',N'@Value0 varchar(5)',@Value0='value'
```

this sql command execute near 22 seconds. I fount that it happens because I have a parameter sniffing..
If add to end of SQL command **option(recompile)** it's work fast: 0 seconds was shown in Managements studio

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) * FROM mytableView WHERE ([Name]) LIKE 
  (''%'' + (@Value0) + ''%'') ORDER BY [Id] DESC 
    option(recompile)',N'@Value0 varchar(5)',@Value0='value'
```

Is it possible to recompile/recreate/erase/update execution plan for my SQL command to work without option(recompile)?

I have tried to apply

- UPDATE STATISTICS
- sp_recompile
- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
- DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0)
- DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
- ALTER INDEX and REBUILD WITH
  unfortunately all this actions didn't help me.

Comment: Why are you doing this in dynamic sql? Also, the leading wildcard is causing your query to be nonSARGable.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: Sean Lange:I have a grid with filter options. When user type *somevalue* in a grid I generate SQL command with leading wildcard. So I just transform '*' to '%'

Comment: GarethD: I read that option(recompile) add some overhead because it rebuilds the execution plan every time that your query executes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` hint instead of `RECOMPILE`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) *
                     FROM mytableView
                     WHERE ([Name]) LIKE (''%'' + (@Value0) + ''%'')
                     ORDER BY [Id] DESC
                     option(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN);',
                   N'@Value0 varchar(5)',
                   @Value0 = 'value';
```

The MSDN page for [Query Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) states that OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN:

> Instructs the query optimizer to use statistical data instead of the initial values for all local variables when the query is compiled and optimized, including parameters created with forced parameterization.

This hint instructs the optimizer to use the **total number of rows for the specified table** divided by the **number of distinct values for the specified column** (i.e. average rows per value) as the row estimate instead of using the statistics of any particular value. As pointed out by @GarethD in a comment below: since this will possibly benefit some queries and possibly hurt others, it needs to be tested to see if the overall gain from this is a net savings over the cost of doing the RECOMPILE. For more details check out: [How OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN Works](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/06/how-optimize-for-unknown-works/).

And just to have it stated, depending on the distribution of the data and what values are passed in, if there is a particular value being used that has a distribution that is fairly representative of most of the values that could be passed in (even if wildly different from some values that won't ever be passed in), then you can target that value by using `OPTIMIZE FOR (@Value0 = 'representative value')` rather than `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`.

Please note that this query hint is only needed for queries that have:

- parameters supplied by variables
- the field(s) in question do not have a fairly even distribution of values (and hence different values passed in via the variable could generate different plans)

The following scenarios were identified in comments below and do not all require this hint, so here is how to address each situation:

- `select top 80 * from table order by id desc`
  There is no variable being passed in here so no query hint needed.
- `select top 80 * from table where id < @lastid order by id desc`
  There is a variable being passed in here, but the [id] field, by its very nature, is evenly distributed, even if sparse due to some deletes, hence no query hint needed (or at least should not be needed).
- `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM mytableView WHERE ([Name]) LIKE (''%'' + (@Value0) + ''%'') ORDER BY [Id] DESC`
  There is a variable being passed in here, and used in such a way that there could be no indication of consistent numbers of matching rows for different values, especially due to not being able to use an index as a result of the leading `%`. THIS is a good opportunity for the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` hint as discussed above.
- If there is a situation where a variable is passed in that has a greatly varying distribution of matching rows, but not many possible values to get passed in, and the values that are passed in are re-used frequently, then those can be concatenated (after doing a `REPLACE(@var, '''', '''''')` on it) directly into the Dynamic SQL. This allows for each of those values to have their own separate yet reusable query plan. Other variables should be sent in as parameters as usual.

  For example, a lookup value for [StatusID] will only have a few possible values and they will get reused frequently but each particular value can match a vastly different number of rows. In that case, something like the following will allow for separate execution plans that do not need either the RECOMPILE or OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN hints as each execution plan will be optimized for that particular value:

  ```
  IF (TRY_CONVERT(INT, @StatusID) IS NULL)
  BEGIN
     ;THROW 50505, '@StatusID was not a valid INT', 55;
  END;

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP (10) * FROM myTableView WHERE [StatusID] = '
             + REPLACE(@StatusID, N'''', N'''''') -- really only needed for strings
             + N' AND [OtherField] = @OtherFieldVal;';

  EXEC sp_executesql
                 @SQL,
                 N'@OtherFieldVal VARCHAR(50)',
                 @OtherFieldVal = @OtherField;
  ```

  Assuming two different values of @StatusID are passed in (e.g. `1` and `2`), there will be two execution plans cached matching the following queries:

  - `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM myTableView WHERE [StatusID] = 1 AND [OtherField] = @OtherFieldVal;`
  - `SELECT TOP (10) * FROM myTableView WHERE [StatusID] = 2 AND [OtherField] = @OtherFieldVal;`

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to calculate execution plan every time when I run SQL command because I have a lot of similar query and I would like to use come saved plan to avoid a overhead.
But you answer gives me an idea to call option(Optimize) in case when SQL command contains 'Like' operator!

Comment: @driver : this option does not recalculate the plan every time. That is the idea of it, else it would be the same as RECOMPILE. It is designed for the purpose that you are needing.

Comment: srutzky:what will happen when I add option(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) to my SQL command and run the same SQL with same parameter and different parameter value?
 With first run will be created an execution plan according to actual statistics and save in some cache and second time if statistics does not change will use the same plan?

Comment: @driver Why ask me what will happen when it is faster and less debatable to just test it out on your system? That will give you a definitive answer. But it is safe to assume that it will _not_ redo all of the original work as that would make it no different than RECOMPILE.

Comment: sorry I didn't want to ask you what is faster, I chek that that with OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN works fast(0 seconds). But I would like to ask you if you know how it works under hood... I mean if I run first SQL with parameter Value0 = 'value' and after that run the same SQL with  Value0 = 'someothervalue'. Will SQL server put plan to the cache and use the saved plan from cache for second SQL?

Comment: [This article should help](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/06/how-optimize-for-unknown-works/) - but to answer your question, no the query won't be recompiled when you use optimise for unknown, it will create a plan based on an "average" value, and use that plan for all values passed. This prevents a plan being created on an outlying value, but it does still mean that a suboptimal plan is used for some values. It very much depends on your data, and how often you run the query as to whether the cost of recomplilation exceeds the cost of running the queries with the wrong plan.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for providing that link. I will include that in an update to this answer. But first, driver, how much variation is there in the value passed in for the LIKE clause? Or, how often is the same value passed in?

Comment: @driver Did you see the link that Gareth posted? Or my questions?

Comment: @GarethD,@srutzky thanks for link and answers - is very helpful for me! Frequency of SQL commands depends on users and which process they run.. When they open a grid, simple sql will be run 'select top 80 * from table order by id desc' when they scroll down, will run new sql 'select top 80 * from table where id < lastid order by id desc' when they enter a filter like '%some value%'  it will run sql as I wrote in  my question. So I generate a lot of different SQL on the same view and that was reason why I afraid to use options for all my SQL command and prefer to left this choice on sql server

Comment: @srutzky, I marked You answer as correct, option(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) helped to speed up query. Please, add the link provided by GarethD to you answer.
I will discus with software architect ability to change SQL generation with  adding option(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) for all SQL commands(or only for commands that contains LIKE operator). Many thanks guys for you answers and you time!

Comment: @driver Thanks. But this is why it is very important to give as much info in the question as possible. I am not recommending OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN for all queries. It simply is not needed. I have updated my answer with a more thorough recommendation based on the new info. The last item is why I had asked about the variation of values, etc.