# sp_executesql uses wrong execution plan

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a query that gets results immediately without `EXEC sp_executesql`,
but when I use `sp_executesql` sql server uses a different executaion plan and it takes over 5 mins to get result.

I also tried `EXEC sp_updatestats` and `dbcc freeproccache` and yet `sp_executesql` chooses the wrong execution plan.

When I use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, it gets result instantly, but I don't want use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in every query.

How can I make `sp_executesql` to choose the right execution plan?

Comment: what plan does it use without using `sp_executesql`? what plan does it use with it? what is the difference causing the time difference, and the difference in parameters being input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My index was a **filtered index** and it seems `sp_executesql` can not use **filtered indexes**! i removed the filter from my index and recreated it and my problem was solved.

Comment: This may have been true in the past, but at least in 2021 using Sql Managed Instance sp_executesql can use filtered indexes.  There is an issue where filtered indexes will not be used for parameters - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5080/how-to-overcome-the-sql-server-filtered-index-unmatchedindexes-issue/

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you're describing is probably a result of [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). You should check out some of these existing posts on this topic:

- [SQL Parameter Sniffing Possible Workaround](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74159/sql-parameter-sniffing-possible-workaround)
- [sp_executesql, Parameters and Parameter Sniffing](http://www.scarydba.com/2013/09/05/sp_executesql-parameters-and-parameter-sniffing/)
- [T-SQL parameter sniffing recompile plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230867/t-sql-parameter-sniffing-recompile-plan)

Comment: thanks, parameter sniffing is when we use different parameters but my parameters are the same for all tests and even after i clear the cache, sp_executesql still chooses the wrong plan.

Comment: @BanafsheAlipour can you show your query? Does it have "catch all" logic? Like `where col=@p or @p is null`?

Comment: my query is like this: `select count(*) from MyTable where col1=@p0 and col2=@p1 `

Comment: @BanafsheAlipour what are the datatypes of the columns and of the parameters?